# Globe legend in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend, global-scene

How do I build a legend in ArcGIS Pro, working with a Global Scene view?

If I work in a normal map, then in the "Insert" tab there is a legend function, and if I work with the globe, then this tab is not there.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @YogeshChavan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386964/globe-legend-in-arcgis-pro#comment633798_386964):

> The legend is only active when working in a layout view

and from [your comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386964/globe-legend-in-arcgis-pro#comment634069_386964) it looks like when you used your global scene in a map frame on a layout view you were able to insert a legend to go with the layers in it.